# How can I calculate illumination requirements for a single CMOS camera photodiode?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons

I am trying to calculate the required illumination in Lux given the sensor parameters of a CMOS camera that will saturate a photodiode, however I have not been able to find a simple model to do this.

The parameters that I think are relevant, and that are available to me are:

- Full well charge: 14500 e-
- DN conversion efficiency: 0.27 DN/e-
- Responsivity: 0.16 DN/photon
- Quantum efficiency: 55%

I know that these parameters are for a particular wavelength, temperature, etc... but I am mainly looking for a model that I can use.
As I see it these parameters could provide some relationship between number of electrons, photons and Digital Numbers (DN), but I don't know the relationship between number of photons and light intensity in lux.

Comment: Could I ask where you got that QE? Not that I doubt it, but I was looking for a value a few years ago (for a particular device) and couldn't find even range estimates.

Comment: The parameters came from the sensor manufacturer's datasheet, sometimes if you look in the camera specs it is not there, in that case you should check the sensor datasheet. The value above comes from: http://www.cmosis.com/products/product_detail/cmv50000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saturation doesn't depend on the DN it is only the number of electrons the pixel can hold, and the number of photons/electron.

In this case 14500e- / 0.55 = 26500 photons

Lux, as you say depends on wavelength, but if you simplify it to the single green wavelength at the peak of the distribution this is 630Lux = 1W/m^2 or 1 lux = 1.5mW/m^2

A photon of 550nm is 3.6E-19J so 1.5mW = 0.0015 JS^-1/ 3.6E-19J = 4E15 photon/s